# Puzzle on multi source file link in "TCPL"

Tags: c, linker

While I'm reading "TCPL", a puzzle come out, I try to explain it but failed.
See below image:[Page 74 in "TCPL"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cDT6.png)
1. `"getop.c"` and `"stack.c"` both include `"calc.h"` while `"getch.c"` doesn't.
However, in `"calc.h"` It also declares function `int getch(void)` and `void ungetch(int)` defined in `"getch.c"`.
2. The program runs correctly.

My question is: How does the header file `"calc.h"` build connection with source file `"getch.c"` while not `include"..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function definition is also a declaration. So there is no need in "getch.c" to explicitly declare `getch` and `ungetch`. It is still a good idea to include "calc.h" to make sure the definition in "getch.c" matches the declarations used in the other c-files

Comment: That means I can also remove `include"calc.h"` in "getop.c" and "stack.c" without effection?

Comment: If you don't call a function in a translation unit, you don't need to declare it. So if you don't call any functions declared in "calc.h" from "getop.c" or "stack.c" you don't need to include "calc.h". But is a VERY good idea to keep the include, that way the compiler can complain if the definitions does not match the declarations.